# Mapa Android Versão 2 com biblioteca de supporte

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou utilizando a api v2 do mapas do Android.

Tenho na minha Activity a seguinte declaração

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

E o seguinte código para recuperar a Mapa:

```
 GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Esta código apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
 Error:(150, 79) java: inconvertible types
  required: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
  found:    android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Como faço para utilizar a versão 2 dos mapas do android quando estou usando a API de compatibilidade?

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar a api de compatibilidade você precisa fazer duas alterações no seu código.

No xml, adicionar a classe do mapa da api de compatibilidade:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

E na sua activity:

```
    GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Isso irá corrigir seu erro.

Você pode conseguir mais informações acessando a documentação oficial [em inglês](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)